# HTML form not submitting long string

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an easy HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <br />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" />
    <br />
    <label>Department</label>
    <input type="text" name="department" />
    <br />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Employee">
</form>
```

When I click submit this will write the input to the DB.
I was always testing with very short names (a few letters). It works so now I tried some longer strings and it fails. I don't see an error but no data is written to my DB.

I can write 25 characters inside the box. So everything till 25 chars is inside the DB, all what is longer isn't.

Comment: HTML is not a problem. Show PHP code instead. Do you have DB `VARCAHR(25)` ?

Comment: Database field not enough length?

Comment: the problem is not with php I think. What is the size of the column in db

Comment: What is your database table structure? Im guessing varchar(25)

Comment: @SagarV I'll check. It's just a 'default' DB created in docker (created by defining environment variables).

Comment: But normally if the database field has only 25 charactes, and you have a longer string it just will be cutted.

Comment: i think it is schema problem you should change db schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a HTML problem, as HTML does not behave like that (well, unless you use maxlength for the input).

This has to be a database issue. Your table probally has a `VARCHAR(25)` in it's structure. When you enter a longer string than it can contain, it *truncates*  the remainder of the string. Thats why you do see the first 25 chars.

You can check this via your database management, like PHPmyAdmin. Go to the matching table, click 'structure'. You can also edit it here to a more appropriate length.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I used postgres in docker to connect with, I can create a DB and table etc with ENV VAR's and than it's using the public default schema which is max 25 varchar: `first_name | character varying(25) |`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem from HTML. Please check your php code and database table structure.

Might be there is input length defined for the field i.e. 25.

Comment: Hi Ankit, this is more a comment than an answer. First, This answer has already been given (in this case by me). Only add our answer when you think your answer explains it better. Also, no need for the ' let me know', that is not how this forum works. If the OP has a question, they can place it as a comment under your answer (like I do now)

Comment: Ohh sorry .. my stack page is not refreshed...My mistake I m sorry